# Javascript Input value formatting

Tags: javascript, input, format, mootools

I would like to format an input field value.
Only numbers and letters, and after the first 8 characters a space and then always after 5 characters.
Limit to 39 characters (actually 33, but 39 plus spaces)

Currently, I'm doing this so (Event "keyup"):

```
var target      = textField,
    position    = target.selectionEnd,
    length      = target.value.length;

target.value    = target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Za-z]/g, '').replace(/(.{5})/g, '$1 ').trim().toUpperCase().substr(0, 39);
target.selectionEnd = position += ((target.value.charAt(position - 1) === ' ' && target.value.charAt(length - 1) === ' ' && length !== target.value.length) ? 1 : 0);
```

Example now:
AT93J OE83J J392F JEOKE 3825H J4HFZ 39F

For example, as it should be:
AT93J0E8 3JJ39 2FJE0 KE382 5HJ4H FZ39F

Can someone help me?
Sorry for my english.

Many thanks!
best regards Stephan

Comment: You need a mask for the input. Or something custom made like this http://jsfiddle.net/n5m6nhg9/